# Getting the dte2 or TeamFoundationServerExt object in a VS Package project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vspackage

I am working on a Visual Studio Package project. This project needs a connection to our TFS. To read the current connection, I would need the TeamFoundationServerExt object, which I should be able to get from the dte2 object.

Now I found hundreds of examples and most of them are working with an "_application" variable, which seems to get automatically filled, but of course not for the "Visual Studio Package" project type.

How can I get the TeamFoundationServerExt object of the currently running VS2010?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to do the following from a VSPackage to get the current DTE object:

```
DTE2 dte = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2;
```

You may also need to check that your package isn't in [a "Zombie" (i.e. starting up) state](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsxteam/archive/2008/06/09/dr-ex-why-does-getservice-typeof-envdte-dte-return-null.aspx) in case you're getting null from the GetService call.

Comment: Thx, the Zombie-state was the important part!